# Redirect localhost requests to a Linux container

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, localhost, lxc

I run a few Linux containers, each running a webapp, on my Ubuntu host. To access the webapps, I use `iptables` to forward port:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <port> -j DNAT --to-destination #<container_ip>:<port>
```

This work well if the traffic comes from *outside* of my host. If the request is done by localhost it doesn't work:

```
 curl <host_ip>:<port>       #works (from outside the host)
 curl <container_ip>:<port>  #works (from inside the host)
 curl 127.0.0.1:<port>       #doesn't work (from inside the host)
```

I understand that packet coming from localhost do not go through the iptables DNAT rule and that is why it's not working. Is there anyway to get this working ?

Comment: Yes, nat table only apply to incoming traffic. It has no sense try to reach another machine using 127.0.0.1.

Comment: well it does make sense in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to solutions not involving `iptables`, you could just run a simple proxy server (like [balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html) or [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) or [pen](http://siag.nu/pen/) or something) to intercept traffic to `localhost` and pass it to your containers.

Comment: Ok, confirmed that this is not possible using iptables. The only way is to use some kinds of proxy as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

@Brigo: That is incorrect. The nat table can contain an OUTPUT chain. The problem is that the nat table's PREROUTING chain is not applied to the loopback interface.

@rmonjo, use the OUTPUT chain in addition to the PREROUTING chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport <port> -j DNAT \
--to-destination #<container_ip>:<port>
```

Edit: this doesn't work. I was thinking of the REDIRECT target which won't solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you, I got really enthusiastic about this answer but it doesn't work. Now when I `curl 127.0.0.1:3100`, curl just does nothing (no more "couldn't connect to host", at least before it times out). What am I missing ?

Comment: Yep, I'm wrong.

Comment: For me this safed my day when from within the host connecting to `<host_ip>:<port>` instead of `127.0.0.1:<port>` what the OP  tried. `<host_ip>:<port>` was rejected before adding your IPTABLES rule, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i've spend a lot of time trying to get iptables to do this trick, but somehow if you add a dnat target to the output chain of the nat table further processing of the packet seems to stop.

Debugging of iptables can be done with this trick: http://backreference.org/2010/06/11/iptables-debugging/

A graphical overview of the packet flow in Linux also helps: http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png

i've resorted to xinetd to solve my problem, see [Forwarding the endpoint (at localhost) of an SSH -L tunnel to another machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/542016/forwarding-the-endpoint-at-localhost-of-an-ssh-l-tunnel-to-another-machine)

Comment: It does this because DNAT is disposative.  You have to arrange your rules in precedential order with nondisposative rules ordinally prior to disposative ones.