# Forwarding the endpoint (at localhost) of an SSH -L tunnel to another machine

Tags: ssh, iptables, localhost, forwarding, tunnel

Even after long searching and trying I'm not able to solve the following puzzle:

```
Client A --------------------------> Server B (172.26.15.15/24)
  ssh -L 4321:localhost:4321         Server C (172.26.15.16/24)
```

- Client 'A' has a ssh tunnel, forwarding a:4321 to b (localhost):4321
- 'Server B' should forward all packets received on localhost:4321 to 'Server C:4321'

Can this be done with `iptables` and, if so, can anybody give me a clue how?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to make this more complicated then it needs to be.  Put in the IP of server C instead of localhost.

```
ssh -L 4321:172.26.15.16:4321
```

The `-L` option [localaddress:]localport:remoteaddress:remoteport

- [localaddress:] (Optional specify the local IP SSH will bind to.  By default it will bind to all IPs.
- localport the local TCP port that SSH will bind the tunnel to
- remotehost - ip address, or DNS reachable from the SSH server and resolved by the SSH server.
- remoteport - a TCP port that is the other end of the tunnel.

Comment: Forget to mention; i have many 'A' clients, and 'Server C' is not static. Administrating the whole system will be a lot easier if i only have to change a few rules on 'Server B' instead of changing all clients.

Comment: What do you mean by not static?  Just use a DNS name instead?  Add the name to the servers /etc/hosts file or something?

Comment: the address of 'Server C' changes sometimes on the network on the '172.26.15.0' network; adjusting this on all clients (200+) will be a lot of work. 

I already (think) i figured out that the incoming traffic from the tunnel (as seen from B side) does not hit the prerouting chain.

Comment: Right, so DNS is the method that lets you map names to addresses, and can be updated easily.

Comment: OK, so you suggest to use on the client something like:
    ssh -L4321<FQDN>:4321
and have FQDN resolve to the 'Server c' address?

Can i use a domain name in a -L statement?

Comment: Yes, **I tell you three times and done**.  Use DNS, dns works as an option for -L the name is resolved by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding traffic originating at localhost with destination localhost can be done with a port forwarding daemon, e.g. xinetd.

I solved my problem with:

*/etc/xinetd.conf:*

```
service local_forward
{
flags = IPv4
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
redirect = 172.26.15.16 4321
}
```

*/etc/services:*

```
local_forward   4321/tcp
```